# XenServer multiple ISO storage repo

Tags: storage, xenserver, iso, xencenter

I'm using XenServer7.2. My ISO images are organized in a hierarchy, which is tree structure in a remote file system (SMB/CIFS). For instance, Ubuntu 16.04 is in Linux/Ubuntu/Xenial. How can I add a storage repo (SR) to the XenServer (7.2) that includes everything?

I know I can add a separate SR for every leaf directory (containing only ISO files, but not DIRs). But there are too many of them, i.e. Windows/10/7/XP, Linux/Fedora/Ubuntu/CentOS, VMware, Citrix, etc. If I only add the top level directory (containing only DIRs), Xen doesn't detect any ISO files. Is there an efficient way to add all ISO files, recursively? Thanks.

Comment: The iso storage is hosted on what OS ? I gave in head a manual step with mklink, possibly scriptable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. SMB/CIFS host is out of my control. I can mount but not allowed to change things. I guess it's a windows server.

Comment: ok, my tip wont work then, it would had been a script that create file link in the main folder with subdolder .iso, as I think its a xenserver limitation to list just the target folder